# C11 network programming

Tags: c, network-programming, c11

I've been reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) and tried to compile the first few example programs ([section 5.1](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfo)) using the `std=c11` flag with `gcc`. I keep getting errors like these (`showip.c`):

```
showip.c: In function ‘main’:
showip.c:15:21: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
     struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
                     ^
showip.c:35:33: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                                 ^
showip.c:41:14: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
              ^
showip.c:42:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
             struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
                                                               ^
showip.c:46:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
             struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
                                                                 ^
showip.c:52:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
```

However, without the `c11` flag it compiles fine. What is exactly causing this incompatibility? And should I even be using C11 for these kind of things?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer this question. How is `struct addrinfo` defined? Does it contain a construct which is treated differently in C11? the `incomplete type` messages are a fairly big hint.

Comment: you need to show more code, we cannot answer it like this, I know the book you are reading, i read it as well, so you need to show more code

Comment: Adding std=c11 undefines __USE_POSIX macro which guards addrinfo struct in netdb.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C11 can only be relevant here in the sense that this excludes some OS specific directories for include files. Try to use `-std=gnu11` which is the C11 variant plus OS and gcc specific extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Without `-std` GCC defaults to a GNU dialect of ISO C90 (C11 with the upcoming 5.0). This will make everything available. But with the `-std=c11` option you're saying that you only want ISO C11 features. `struct addrinfo` and the related functions are POSIX features. [The man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) tells you how to make those available:

```
   getaddrinfo(), freeaddrinfo(), gai_strerror():
       _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

So define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as `1` before including the header. Either by using `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1` or `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=1`.